Why is my Android activity's ConfigChanged handler not being called for system language changes?
My game is based on NativeActivity and registers for these config changes in AndroidManifest.xml
android:configChanges="locale">

I've implemented config changes in my C++ command handler like this.
case APP_CMD_CONFIG_CHANGED:
{
    char language[3];
    language[2] = '\0';
    AConfiguration_getLanguage(app->config, language);
    Dprintf("APP_CMD_CONFIG_CHANGED: %s\n", language);
} break;

On a Samsung phone I follow these steps.

Launch my game
Background my game
Open Settings app
Go to General Management -> Language
Change language
Go to task list and choose my game
My game comes back to the foreground

At no point in the above process did I receive a APP_CMD_CONFIG_CHANGED command. Is my expectation correct that I should receive one? If so then what is wrong with my implementation?
